# Java checkbox positioning

Tags: java, swing

I'm relatively new to Java and I am creating a login form. The problem I am having is the position of the checkbox seen in the picture below, I am trying to assign it to start directly below the "P" in "Password.

[image: this is the application when it is running]

Here is the code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;

public class Login extends JPanel{

private static JLabel usernameLabel, passwordLabel;
private static JTextField usernameField;
private static JPasswordField passwordField;
private static JCheckBox checkBox;
private static JButton loginButton;
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

public Login(){

    //layout
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    //spacing between each component
    gbc.insets = new Insets(1,1,1,1);


    //new instance of objects
    usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
    passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
    usernameField = new JTextField(10);
    passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
    checkBox = new JCheckBox("Keep me logged in");
    loginButton = new JButton("Login");

    //username label    
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(usernameLabel, gbc);

    //password label
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    add(passwordLabel, gbc);

    //username textfield
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;  
    add(usernameField, gbc);

    //password textfield
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    add(passwordField, gbc);

    //keep logged in checkbox
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    add(checkBox, gbc);

    //login button
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    add(loginButton, gbc);
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure why the checkbox isn't in-line with the labels, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
checkBox = new JCheckBox("");
checkBoxLabel = new JLabel("Keep me logged in");
```

Then when you are adding your components

```
//keep logged in checkbox
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    add(checkBox, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    add(checkBoxLabel);
```

Comment: I understand why and how you have done this, it works but i was wondering if there is a way to merge the two "cells" like you would be able to do on Microsoft Excel for example.

Comment: you can do GridBagConstraints.gridSpan = 2. But then you will lose the lined up columns for that row

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `fill` Property of `GridBagConstraints`

```
  //username label    
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;//this will do the trick
```